# What is the difference between making HttpRequest and Forwarding HttpRequest?

Tags: java, spring, http, httprequest, netflix-zuul

Lets say my client (Browser) request my java service (Service A).

`http://localhost:8080/getDataFromB`

Based on the request, from my Service A, I need to make another HttpRequest to either Service B or Service C to get the data.

`getDataFromB: http://serverb.com/getDataFromB`

`getDataFromC: http://serverc.com/getDataFromC`

I tried making HttpRequest to Service B and Service C based on the request. But should I do it ? or Should I forward the requests the service B or Service C ? If So I save some TCP connection requests on my side.

What will be difference between making HttpRequest vs forwarding the requests

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your client to know that you're actually serving the response from B or C, you should forward the request to either B or C.

If you want your client to know that your server will not be handling A directly, but instead will do B or C – so perhaps in the future the client can ask for B or C directly instead of asking for A – then you should send a redirect to the client.

You could instead do what you're suggesting - your server handles incoming request, then makes a separate HTTP request to B or C – but that would just add more complexity to how your server communicates back with the original client. If your server logic somehow "fits" with this approach, I would consider stepping back and re-thinking your server logic to either handle requests directly, or handle it with either a redirect or forward.

Unless your server is unable to handle new inbound requests due to excessive TCP connections, I wouldn't worry about optimizing for that.